# Convert SQL left join to Linq Lambda Expression

Tags: sql, linq-to-entities

I have this SQL query

```
select at.description, 
       a.Address1, 
       a.Address2, 
       a.City
  from address_types at
  left join Address a
    on a.addresstype = at.addresstype
    and a.addressid=24
```

Would like to write it in Linq Lambda Expression, any clue?

Thanks!

Comment: Some idea from MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rather simplify it in following way

```
(from at in address_types
join a in address 
on at.addresstype  equals a.addresstype  into tt
from ar in tt.DefaultIfEmpty()
where (ar != null && ar.addressid == 24)
select new 
 {
    at.Description,
    ar.Address1, 
    ar.Address2, 
    ar.City 
  })
```

The reason why we don't need this check "(ja == null)" is because we already restricted our set in this line "where (ar != null && ar.addressid == 24)".

Meanwhile this query works, my POV is that LEFT JOIN is also redundant here in the SQL query. You will not get NULL rows due to your condition "a.addressid = 24" so SQL can be rewritten to INNER JOIN and LINQ query as well to

```
(from at in address_types
    join a in address 
    on at.addresstype  equals a.addresstype
    where at.addressid == 24
    select new 
     {
        at.Description,
        a.Address1, 
        a.Address2, 
        a.City  
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
  var resultset = (from at in addresstypes
                   join a in addresses
                    on at.AddressType equals a.AddressType into joinaddress
                   from ja in joinaddress.DefaultIfEmpty()
                   where (ja != null && ja.AddressID == 24)
                   select new 
                     {
                        AddressType = at.AddressType,
                        AddressID = ja == null ? 0 : ja.AddressID,
                        Address1 = ja== null ? string.Empty : ja.Address1
                      });
```

Comment: I think "ja == null ? 0 ..." is redundant, because you already added condition "where (ja != null && ja.AddressID == 24)"

Comment: @Madman: Yes, that would be redundant in this case. But if we were to perform true left join (show blank values from right list where join condition does not match), we will need these checks. Let me know your thoughts.